# issue when implementing a non-blocking publishing mechanism with zeromq

Tags: python, nonblocking, zeromq

I would like to communicate two processes (sender and receiver) using zeromq. Now, if the receiver process is not running, I would like that the sender process continues its execution, even if the message is lost.

Trying to implement it using the PUB-SUB pattern, I have noticed that if the receiver is not running, the sender hangs up. For instance, in the following sender source code:

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
sender = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
sender.connect("tcp://localhost:5555")

sender.send("Sending to nobody", NOBLOCK)

print "Msg sent"
```

when the receiver is down, the message "Msg sent" is never printed, and the sender remains in "sender.send("Sending to nobody", NOBLOCK)" forever. Besides, I have tried to check if the receiver is up or not getting the return of the *connect* function, but it is always "None" in both cases.

I am using Python 2.6.5 and zeromq 2.1

Somebody knows what it is happening or an alternative solution? (I have tried using PULL-PUSH, and REQ-REP but similar results)

Thank very much in advance

Comment: That code doesn't actually run (the NOBLOCK symbol isn't defined).  It really helps to post code that people can cut and paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After fixing your sample:

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
sender = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
sender.connect("tcp://localhost:5555")

sender.send("Sending to nobody", zmq.NOBLOCK)

print "Msg sent"
```

The behavior I see is that the "Msg sent" phrase is printed, but the script hangs after that and never actually exits.  The problem here is that it it is hanging on the `close()` system call.

You can change this behavior by setting the `LINGER` option on your socket:

```
sender = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
sender.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 100)
```

This value here is the linger time in milliseconds.  See the man page for `zmq_setsockopt` for more information.  The practical impact of this is that ZMQ will only wait for *linger* milliseconds before closing the socket.

Don't set this value *too* low, because that will cause messages to be lost even if the sender is listening (because ZMQ may close the socket before the message has actually been delivered).

Answer (score 3):

You can easily change: `sender.connect("tcp://localhost:5555")` to `sender.bind("tcp://localhost:5555")` and vise-versa on receiver.

It gives you ability to connect receiver wherever you like. Sender would work no matter is there are receivers or not.